# Inverse probability weighting led to a decreased R-squared value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, weights, weighted-regression

I used inverse probability weighting to correct for selection bias in my sample. After including inverse probability weights in my model, I observed that the R2 actually decreased compared to the model without adjusting for selection bias. However, the main predictor of interest became more significant after including inverse probability weights in the model.

So, if including inverse probability weights in the model leads to a low R2, does that mean the weights we have estimated are not good weights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The weights are there, in your own words, to "correct for bias".  So, the bias was increasing $R^2$. I see no reason why this couldn't happen.

$R^2$ isn't the greatest way to evaluate a model but, if anything, a low value of it indicates that your model isn't doing a good job.